# Redis Queue: Is it possible to pause worker in Redis Queue (Python)

Tags: python, redis, queue

I hope you're doing well. I'm currently working on an application that utilizes Redis Queue in Python for managing workers and jobs. We have a robust system in place that allows us to queue and force stop workers efficiently.

However, we recently received a new requirement to implement the ability to pause a running worker and resume a pause worker vice vers. I've been diving into the documentation, but I haven't been able to find a clear solution yet.

I wanted to reach out to this forum to seek your guidance and expertise. Could you please help me determine if it's possible to pause a running worker in Redis Queue? If it is indeed possible, I would greatly appreciate any insights or steps you can share on how to accomplish this.

I'm grateful for any assistance or suggestions you can provide. Thank you in advance for your time and support!